# How to use gnu-parallel for nested loops with inner one depending on the outer one?

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I would like to use gnu-parallel to parallelize the following snippet

```
for a in `seq 5` ; do
    for b in `seq $a` ; do
        echo $a $b
    done
done
```

Is this possible to achieve using something like

```
parallel echo {1} {2} ::: $(seq 5) ::: $(seq {1})
```

The above syntax does not work.

**Motivation:**

I would like to use parallel in order to submit a number of jobs to a cluster, as explained here
http://docs.rcc.uchicago.edu/software/scheduler/parallel/README.html

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel can do the cartesian product. What you want is half of that (the lower triangle of the product). GNU Parallel cannot do that directly. So you will have to skip the upper triangle:

```
parallel [ {2} -gt {1} ] '||' echo {1} {2} ::: $(seq 5) ::: $(seq 5)
```

For more complex tasks use $job->skip():

```
parallel echo {=1' $arg[2] > $arg[1] and $job->skip();' =} {2} ::: $(seq 5) ::: $(seq 5)
```